# PHPExcel - comment background become black in excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using PHPExcel to load and save *.xslx file in PHP.
I load a normal excel file and save it into another file using PHPExcel then all the comments become black comments.

Do you have any idea what it could be?
Thanks

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($loadfilename);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');//Excel2007
$objWriter->save($savefilename);
```

[Here is the result of excel comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/at9G3.png)